# Application translation with Qt: chinese title fails

Tags: qt, translation, special-characters, linguistics

I am working on a multilingual application with Qt4, everything goes alright except for the chinese translation: I get all my texts translated as I want, but windows titles doesn't work.

When I edit the cn.ts file in Qt Linguist it shows the chinese characters, but after lrelease  and application run all my windows titles shows small rectangles as it didn't recognize the characters, only windows titles didn't work the rest(message text button text...) works fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a different font for the Windows titles to everything else? Usually the 'small rectangles' represent the fact that the characters do not exist for the font.

Comment: Thank you but I didn't set a personal font it is by default I didn't change it!!

Comment: Just to test, can you change it to the same font that's working in other text?

Comment: the problem persist even with "setFont()", it is same for messages (message text is fine but not the window title), window opened with getExistingDirectory() also !

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but have you checked the source text characters are ok in the translation file?

Comment: yes the source file is in english and even the chinese translation is readable (Qt Linguist)

Comment: @ouou What happens if you show hard-coded chinese character for a window's title? I.e. can you try with `setWindowTitle("你好");`. If that fails as well, the problem is not connected to translation per se, rather it is a general font problem.

Comment: @ouou Just a quick question - are you on Windows XP by any chance?

Comment: @sashoalm sorry for the late, I am on windows 7, thank you all for your responses but this project is already closed, I remember that I re enter the translated chinese text and re release the project and everything went alright, I didn't know the exact reason for the issue so I couldn't put an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My code was like this:

```
setWindowTitle(self.tr("Pocess B for A ")+str(self.A[0])))
```

I replaced it with:

```
setWindowTitle(self.tr("Pocess B for A %1").arg(self.A[0]))
```

and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Either 1. your desktop environment is set to use a font that doesn't support the characters you are trying to use or 2. you are entering the text into Linguist via a method that results in non-Unicode text coding.

In case of 1:

- Try changing the desktop font for window titles
- Test different titles using other Chinese characters
- Test those strings using a font known to support Chinese but in, say, a `QLabel`
- Run your application using `-locale cn`

In case of 2:

- Try entering Chinese characters into Linguist with an input method that you know supports Unicode
- Ask your translator if they copied and pasted the text into Linguist or typed it directly

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. My code was like this:

`giFaceCompareGUIClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("giFaceCompareGUIClass", "欢迎", 0));`

I replaced it with:

`giFaceCompareGUIClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("giFaceCompareGUIClass", QString::fromLocal8Bit("欢迎").toStdString().c_str(), 0));`

and everything was fine.